# How to make tkinter buttons work in parallel?

Tags: python, tkinter, pynput

I'm writing a script that has to auto-click the mouse. So i use pynput's keyboard and mouse listener and controller.
I am calling my mouse/keyboard controlling script from another program using `multiprocessing` and `Tkinter.Button`.

To click when mouse is HELD (not on trigger-button press) I use a function `click()` (in attached code) and the problem is `KeyboardController` is working and `MouseController` is not.

I have replaced `MouseController` with nearly-the-same function in `pyautogui`.

```
def click(): #function that clicks when LMB is pressed and auto_mode is on
    global bal, auto_mode, delay
    while True:
        sup = time.time()
        if (auto_mode and bal):
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            mouse.release(Button.left)
        diff = time.time() - sup
        time.sleep(max(0, delay - diff))
```

--------------- NOT WORKING (not doing anything)

```
def click():
    global bal, auto_mode, delay
    while True:
        sup = time.time()
        if (auto_mode and bal):
            keyboard.press(Key.enter)
            keyboard.release(Key.enter)
            #mouse.press(Button.left)
            #mouse.release(Button.left)
        diff = time.time() - sup
        time.sleep(max(0, delay - diff))
```

--------------- WORKING (presses <kbd>enter</kbd>)

Comment: Actually `MouseController` is working but not in this script. When i just bind 10 `mouse clicks` to a `trigger-button` press it worked. So the problem not in `MouseController`

Comment: Just now i changed the conditions of clicking to `Hold Enter` and it worked.(Mouse is clicking). But if i use `Hold Mouse` as a condition it is not working

Comment: it wasnt working on linux, but on windows it is OK. i was writing a windows application, so the problem disappeared itself